# Can I bridge two wired networks with a Netgear WG602 (v4)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I have two networks and I want to join them. Only one has a router. The other is currently just a bunch of computers joined via a switch.

So it looks a little like this:

1.

```
Router + comp1 + comp2 + wireless ap (Cisco EPC2425)
```

2.

```
comp3 + comp4 + Netgear WG602
```

Is it possible to use the WG602 to connect to the WIFI of the main network (the one with the router) and connect via wire to the 2nd network - therefore allowing the computers on network 2 to use the router on network 1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible, but you could obtain that from the WG602's [manual](ftp://downloads.netgear.com/files/wg602v2_user_manual.pdf) (section starting on page 49, you'll need to it up to obtain an IP adress from your router in network 1.

However, from what I understand from the manual, **I'd strongly advise you not do this.** This is because for some reason, WPA encryption on the WG602 is not available in bridge modes. You'll have to fall back to WEP encryption, which is **highly insecure**.

EDIT: Reconsidering, I realized that what I wrote above only holds true if you want to bridge several WG602s wirelessly. If you just need to bridge the computers on the WG602's wifi network with the wired router, just hook up the WG602 to a LAN port of the router and enable its DHCP client. That should do.

Comment: Thank you Tobias. Does the AP on network 1 have to be a Netgear also? It isn't; it's a Cisco EPC2425.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but just go ahead and give it a try :)

Comment: Please consider my edit in the answer.